# pass date from datepicker in one activity to another

Tags: android, datepicker

i have a mainactivity which contains date picker which works perfectly
i want to send the date selected in main activity to second activity which basicly just gets it through get intent how can that be done itred below code but it didnot work

main activity

```
package com.Blog.blogname;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

//import org.example.androidsdk.demo.DetailActivity;
//import org.example.androidsdk.demo.MainActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Datepicker extends Activity {
private EditText txtView;
private String initialDate;
private String initialMonth;
private String initialYear;
private DatePickerDialog dialog = null;
Context context;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.datepicker);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    txtView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    context = getApplicationContext();
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar dtTxt = null;

          String preExistingDate = (String) txtView.getText().toString();

          if(preExistingDate != null && !preExistingDate.equals("")){
              StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(preExistingDate,"/");
                  initialMonth = st.nextToken();
                  initialDate = st.nextToken();
                  initialYear = st.nextToken();
                  if(dialog == null)
                  dialog = new DatePickerDialog(v.getContext(),
                                   new PickDate(),Integer.parseInt(initialYear),
                                   Integer.parseInt(initialMonth),
                                   Integer.parseInt(initialDate));
                  dialog.updateDate(Integer.parseInt(initialYear),
                                   Integer.parseInt(initialMonth),
                                   Integer.parseInt(initialDate));

          } else {
              dtTxt = Calendar.getInstance();
              if(dialog == null)
              dialog = new DatePickerDialog(v.getContext(),new PickDate(),dtTxt.getTime().getYear(),dtTxt.getTime().getMonth(),
                                                  dtTxt.getTime().getDay());
              dialog.updateDate(dtTxt.getTime().getYear(),dtTxt.getTime().getMonth(),
                                                  dtTxt.getTime().getDay());
          }

            dialog.show();
        }

    });
}
private class PickDate implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {

        int monthOfYear1 = monthOfYear + 1;
        String formattedMonth = "" + monthOfYear1;
        String formattedDayOfMonth = "" + dayOfMonth;

        if(monthOfYear1 < 10){

            formattedMonth = "0" + monthOfYear1;
        }
        if(dayOfMonth < 10){

            formattedDayOfMonth = "0" + dayOfMonth;
        }


       // view.updateDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
       // txtView.setText(year+"/"+monthOfYear+"/"+dayOfMonth);

         //view.updateDate(year, formattedMonth, formattedDayOfMonth);
        txtView.setText(year+"-"+formattedMonth+"-"+formattedDayOfMonth);

         Intent intent = new Intent(Datepicker.this, SplashActivityDatewiseCurrentAffairs.class);
         intent.putExtra("Date", year+"-"+formattedMonth+"-"+formattedDayOfMonth);  
        dialog.hide();
    }

}
}
```

second activity

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String Date = i.getStringExtra("Date");
```

Comment: Your code seems ok. Then what is the problem? I suggest you first Change your `Activity` name with Different.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to call startActivity(intent)

Comment: Post your logcat. and are you add the intent in the manifest ?